# Native compile python libraries for serverless with serverless-python-requirements

Tags: numpy, docker, python-3.6, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm trying to compile numpy for use in AWS Lambda functions from my windows machine.

I've been following [this](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) simple example of **serverless-python-requirements** for a lambda to print a numpy array.

I run `serverless deploy` from within a virtualenv in my local directory `../numpy-test`

```
(numpy-test) C:\Users\...\numpy-test>serverless deploy
Serverless: Generated requirements from C:\Users\...\numpy-test\requirements.txt in C:\Users\...\numpy-test\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from C:\Users\...\numpy-test\.serverless\requirements\requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (42.86 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
```

My requirements.txt file simply contains

```
numpy==1.13.1
```

and my YML file looks like:

```
service: numpy-test 

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip:non-linux

  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  domains:
    prod: ...
    staging: ...
    dev: ...
```

When I attempt to test the function after upload with `serverless invoke -f numpy --log`  I get the following error

```
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler'"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
START RequestId: 24584f5c-5145-4694-b21b-7c6e4700f985 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'handler':
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

When I download the dependencies directly from AWS lambda, it looks like the package is compiled in windows.

[image]

I have Docker installed and as far as I can tell it's working properly.  I haven't used it before so that's why I'm trying to use this solution as opposed to learning a lot of new commands in Docker.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is going on in your case, but if you want to use `numpy` in Lambda, have a look at [Lambda Layers and the official (AWS) layer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/) with `numpy` and `scipy`.

To use it, add a [`layers` section](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers#using-your-layers) to the function in your serverless.yml

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambda-Python36-SciPy1x:2
```

You might need to change the ARN depending on the AWS region you're targeting.

Comment: I will look into it.  I'm trying to solve the general case of native compiling for arbitrary dependencies, so I won't be able to use the pre-built layers as in the easiest example, but very much like the idea of lambda layers.  Just need to figure out how to successfully compile the dependencies in an aws compatible container xD